# PHP MySQL UPDATE query with no effect

Tags: php, mysql

I am a new PHP coder and I started a project of cms panel with, for start, three options: new article, delete article and edit article. There isn't even one error in my project but, when im trying to edit a post, everything is going well, except the save. The post isn't saved!!! and there aren't any errors! I am trying to fix that problem from yesterday. That's annoying.

Here is part of my code:

editTreat.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    include("includes/functions.php");
    $ctreat = getTreat($_GET["id"]);
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Control panel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="doEditt.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="tName">:Title</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="tName" value="<?php echo $ctreat["Title"]; ?>"></input>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="tContent">:Content</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <textarea name="tContent"> <?php echo $ctreat["Content"]; ?> </textarea>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            CKEDITOR.replace('tContent');
                        </script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit"></input></td>
                    <td> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

doEditt.php:

```
   <?php
    include("includes/functions.php");
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if(isset($_POST["tName"])) {
            editTreat($_POST["tName"],$_POST["tContent"],$_POST["id"]);
            header("Location: treatments.php");
        } else {
            echo "Please fill the title";
            include("editTreat.php");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: editTreat.php");
    }
?>
```

part of my includes/functions.php:

```
    function editTreat($tName, $tContent, $id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `treatments` SET title = '$tName', content = '$tContent' WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    header("Location: treatments.php");
}

function getTreat($id) {
    $id = (int) $id;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `treatments` WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}
```

So, if you can help me, please help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you run it in phpmyadmin or similar tool to see if the query itself works?

Comment: Problem #1 is you're not [escaping your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this code has severe vulnerabilities that could be exploited. Problem #2 is you're using `mysql_query` which is slated to be removed in future versions of PHP because of things like Problem #1. You should be using something like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to do this properly, safely, and in a future-proof way. If you're new to PHP, do not learn the old, antiquated methods for doing things.

Comment: also, be warned mysql_ functions are depreaced for a reason and  will  cease to work in a while. - But I cannot see anything wrong with your sql, so I agree with @JohnConde.

Comment: Is `editTreat` function being called with the expected parameters? check the values it receives

Comment: I tryed to insert this row:
UPDATE treatments SET title = 'Something', content = 'Content' WHERE ID = '30'

and i got: 0 rows affected.
edit: how i can do it without mysql_query?

thanks

Comment: You don't do any error checking. For instance, `mysql_query()` returns `false` in case of error. You should verify that. To make it worse, you direct to another page right after that, so you won't see on screen error messages.

Comment: There aren't any error messages

Comment: Is someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

On line 4 you reference id lower case

```
$ctreat = getTreat($_GET["id"]);
```

Notice Lowercase id

Then in the form you reference ID Uppercase

```
<?php echo $_GET["ID"]; ?>
```

PHP is case sensitive... is id upper or lower case

The posting ID is not getting sent to the submit form, this looks to be your issue.

Comment: I tried to echo the results and i got:
title
content
0 (this is the id)
and it steel see the same also whith upper case...

Comment: Please do a desc table_name and post the results... I think this is a case sensitivity issue either in both the view and/or the save function.

Comment: can you also add and echo of the SQL statement, it might help as well to get to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Some obvious issues:

1. I'm sure **id** column is not string so why quotes?

   ```
   UPDATE `treatments` SET title = '$tName', content = '$tContent' WHERE ID = $id
   ```
2. You should escape any user input.

   ```
   $tName = mysql_real_escape_string($tName);
   ```
3. PHP is case sensitive, and you use diferent case for `$_GET["id"]`. Im sure you want to use `$_GET["id"]`!

   ```
   $ctreat = getTreat($_GET["id"]);
   VERSUS
   echo $_GET["ID"];
   ```

Comment: Not working...
   I did all what you tell me to do and it's not working!

Comment: I'm really sorry. Check your DB to see whether edited topics exits. Desable all the `Location: ` redirects. Instead, put some `echo ...` debug here. Also `print_R($_GET)` and `$_POST`.

Comment: I disabled all the Location: and i got that id = 0